# NSPredicate for evaluating a String

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspredicate, nspredicateeditor

How do I evaluate a string using `NSPredicate`?

I have used `NSPredicateControl` and String manipulations to get something like, `N92 BEGINSWITH[cd] "n"`. I want to evaluate this to get a True/False value. How do I get that? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[cd]%@", @"n"];
NSString *yourValue=@"nndfj";
BOOL result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:yourValue];
if (result ==YES)
{
    NSLog(@"Word begin with n");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Word does not begin with n");
}
```